# Why would someone want to sell a bond for 50% less than what they paid?

Tags: investing, bonds

I was looking on DeGiro and I saw some corporate bonds up for sale for very low amounts e.g. 34.11 and 52.00. Since the standard or baseline amount is 100.00 these bonds seem to be up for sale for 520 eur and 341.10 eur instead of 1000 eur. Is that assumption correct?

If my assumption is correct, what reasons would a seller have to take such a hit to sell the bond?

[image]
[image]

Comment: XS0439764191 appears to be a zero coupon bond maturing in 2044.

Comment: Equity prices are easy to understand: the price advertised is the cost of a share... not so much with bonds; they're priced completely differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Since the standard or baseline amount is 100.00 these bonds seem to be up for sale for 520 eur and 341.10 eur instead of 1000 eur. Is that assumption correct?

No - bonds do not always sell for their par value. If the coupon rate of a bond is close to the *yield* that you get with other bonds of similar default risk, then the price will be close to par.

This is a different case, though. These bonds *do not pay a coupon*. You pay a relatively low price upfront in exchange for a larger payout at the end. The "return" that you get if you hold the bond to maturity is the difference between the face value and what you paid for it (typically much less than face value).

In other words, you pay 34.11 now in exchange for getting 100 *in 2044*. That's a compounded annual return of about 4.8% per year.

As zero-coupon bonds get closer to maturity, their price naturally rises (assuming the default risk does not change significantly) towards the par value. So all else being equal (meaning that interest rates and default probability do not change) the value of this bond should increase by about 4.8% per year, ending up at 100 close to the maturity date.

So it's impossible to know what the holder paid for the bond (although there might be a price history that shows the value of the bond changing over time) to know if they're selling at a profit or loss.

Comment: It might be clearer if you consider that the holder bought the bond in 2014 (say it's a 30 year bond), and would receive 100 if he held it until 2044.  But maybe he needs money now, so if he sells it for 50 now, he makes 15.89 profit plus the return of his original investment.  The purchaser would still make 50 profit if he holds the bond to maturity.